# iOS Local notifications from a background running app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, notifications, background-process

I'm looking for a way to send local notifications on the user device (with a pop-up) from my app running in background (with the location background execution mode which allow to keep running always).

In fact, this app have to check battery level and send local notifications when a certain level is reached.

I have some questions about it that I didn't found answers on the net because of the specificity of this app :

Where can I put my battery level checking method ? I know that the app can keep running with background execution mode but I don't know where to put the test and if I have to do an "if" statement or a notification center observer ?

I tried to put an "if" statement in the location update method (wrong place I guess), and when the app is in background and the battery level reached the level I'm wanting for, there is a notification displayed in the notification center, but there isn't pop-up displayed on the top of the screen, so the user have to go manually in the notification center to see it.

I hope to be understandable, thanks for your futur answers and have a nice day.

Comment: Everything that can be instantiated inside AppDelegate, except ViewControllers and Views, can react on incoming notifications (while your app is in background mode). You could create an own handler and pass the callbacks to it so the handler will be notified about incoming local notification. ... I have no idea how battery level checking works, so I can't really post a good answer.

Comment: Effectively, it seems that the app delegate have to do something. I have a little question : does the NSNotificationCenter method keep running in background ?

Comment: Actually I don't know :D I only used normal local notifications for my needs and never worked with NSNotificationCenter before. You could create a simple app register something and wait for your notification while your App is running in background mode. And you'll see if it fires or not. Don't create anything hard for such testing.

Comment: The very big problem I encounter with this app is that I can't fire the notif to a date because I can't test when the battery reached low level. So I want to make a condition or a notification center observer to test this level, and when it's OK, I fire the notification immediately. But when doing it, the pop-up doesn't appears on the screen (only the notification in the center is displayed)